# Combining regex in order to get version of path

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to implement a Perl regex which checks if the path is in the right format and if so it takes the version. It will be easier to explain with an example. Consider the following path:

```
/bin/src/python/2.7.5/lib/re.py
```

I would like to check if this path is starting with `/bin` and has `python` in it. So I use `^/bin/.*/python/`. But I would like to also get the version `2.7.5` by somehow inserting it into `$1`.

It should be something as following:

```
if ($path =~ "^/bin/.*/python/") {
    $version = $1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the version number always comes after `/python/`, you can just do:

```
if ($path =~ m{^/bin/.*/python/([^/]+)}) {
    $version = $1;
}
```

This will grab the path segment (a series of non-/ characters) after `/python/`.

You can be a bit more fancy and try to validate that the version consists of dotted numbers:

```
if ($path =~ m{^ /bin/ .* /python/ ( [0-9]+ (?: \. [0-9]+ )* ) / }x) {
    $version = $1;
}
```

(This is the point where things get messy enough to break out the `x` flag to allow whitespace in the regex.)